# How to create a jquery datepicker in code behind in ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datetimepicker

I want to use a datetimepicker in aspx page using cs codes.But i have to create it dynamically in cs.I usually use jquery but another solutions can be accepted.

Comment: What have you tried?  What's wrong with the first result for 'jquery datepicker' on google?

Comment: my que "do i use it from code behind ?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Create the Script dynamically that attaches the jquery script to the control:

```
string csname1 = "BindDatePickerScript";
Type cstype = this.GetType();

// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
// Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
{
System.Text.StringBuilder cstext1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
cstext1.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
cstext1.Append("Your Script");
cstext1.Append("});");
cstext1.Append("</");
cstext1.Append("script>");

cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString());
}
```

This Script gets added at the bottom of the HTML rendered page.